# ERROR: pdf file being converted to txt on MAC

Tags: php, macos, download

I have:

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: text/plain');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test filename.pdf"');
 readfile('test filename.pdf');
?>
```

This downloads the pdf file fine on Windows but when it comes to Mac, it's converting the pdf file to .txt resulting to filename.pdf.txt on download & now the file can't be read. Why is Mac doing this?

Comment: well your header is calling it plain text. why are you using that?

Comment: Oh I see. Missed to check that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the mimetype is a TXT file. You'll need to set the mimetype to `application/pdf`.